# No me genera los archivos de un proyecto nuevo de asp.net core vacio

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

Al crear un nuevo proyecto de asp.net core, me muestra como en la imagen 1 sin archivo o cuando
intento abrir un proyecto aparece de esta forma, como podría solucionar este problema, muchas gracias de antemano

[image: imagen1]

[image: imagen2]